# Forcing Backbone to save an attribute as a file

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

Is there a way to use `Model.set` and `Model.save` in a way that will force Backbone to send the data to the server as a file (as if you were submitting a form with an `<input type="file">` tag?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The short answer is no. The long answer is, *sort of*.

This doesn't really have anything to do with `Backbone` and instead is about being able to AJAX a file in the browser. The solution is to use the File API from HTML 5. Below is an example of how you would do that with a `Backbone` model.

Let's assume we have a User model and we want to save an avatar file on that model.

```
// Backbone Model JS

User = Backbone.Model.extend({
  readAvatar : function (file, callback) {
    var reader = new FileReader(); // File API object for reading a file locally
    reader.onload = (function (theFile, self) {
      return function (e) {
        // Set the file data correctly on the Backbone model
        self.set({avatar_file_name : theFile.name, avatar_data : fileEvent.target.result});
        // Handle anything else you want to do after parsing the file and setting up the model.
        callback();
     };
    })(file, this);
    reader.readAsDataURL(file); // Reads file into memory Base64 encoded
  }
});

// Somewhere in your view JS

this.$("input[type='file']").change(function (event) {
  var file = e.originalEvent.target.files[0];
  userModel.readAvatar(file, userModel.save);
});

// HTML
<form><input type="file" name="avatar"/></form>
```

Now on your back end you need to handle the file coming through as Base64 encoded data.

A couple of warnings:

1. If you need extensive browser support then this solution probably won't work for you.
2. Base64 encoding a file is going to increase the amount of data sent over the wire by about 30%.

Comment: I have similar case to create a attributes to the files upload. I have posted my question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20805043/backbonejs-save-files-and-form-data. I want know what I need to change here 'avatar_file_name' and 'avatar_data to my file name 'ImageData'